# No effect on food Collison with snake

Tags: java

I am trying to make a snake game and i want to solve this issue before i continue.i am having problem with the food. The score is not incremented when the snakehead's coordinates matches the food coordinates.My doubt lies in the 'foodPhysics()' method. As I am a beginner, good explanation could be helpful.

```
public class Game2 extends JComponent implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public int x = 350, y = 350;
    public static Game2 game;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;
    public int vx, vy, fx, fy, score;

    public Random generator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = new Game2();
    }

    public Game2() {
        generator = new Random();
        fx = 7 + generator.nextInt(780);
        fy = 7 + generator.nextInt(780);
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setSize(700, 700);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Timer t = new Timer(10, this);

        window.add(this);

        window.addKeyListener(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
        head = new Point(x, y);

        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (up) {
            vy = -10;
            y = y + vy;
        }
        if (down) {
            vy = 10;
            y = y + vy;
        }
        if (left) {
            vx = -10;
            x = x + vx;
        }
        if (right) {
            vx = 10;
            x = x + vx;
        }
        if (x == 0 && vx == -10) {
            x = 800;
            vy = 0;
        }
        if (x == 800 && vx == 10) {
            x = 0;
            vy = 0;
        }
        if (y == 0 && vy == -10) {
            y = 800;
            vx = 0;
        }
        if (y == 800 && vy == 10) {
            y = 0;
            vx = 0;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            up = false;
            down = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = true;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = true;
        }
        if (foodPhysics() == true) {
            score++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
        foodRender(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 25, 25));
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(score), 500, 500);
    }

    public void foodRender(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(fx, fy, 15, 15);
    }

    public boolean foodPhysics() {
        if (x == fx && y == fy) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please reformat the code so it would be possible to read it?

Comment: I have made an edit and reformatted the code for them. It should appear soon. @xenteros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm lead to believe that your code would not compile at this moment. You seem to set a head variable equal to "new Point(x,y)" but you don't have a head variable declared in the code. That aside.

In your foodPhysics() method.

```
public boolean foodPhysics(){
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(fx,fy,15,15) //the size of your food.
    if(rect.contains(head)){                    //you'll need to create this variable 
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This would give you a little bit of a region since in your code the point would only increment whenever it would exactly pass over the same pixel. Be sure to also reset the head in your actionPerformed() method.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (up) {
        vy = -10;
        y = y + vy;
    }
    if (down) {
        vy = 10;
        y = y + vy;
    }
    .
    .
    .

    head = new Point(x,y);

    repaint();
}
```

It would probably also be better if you changed the rendering of the snakehead to something like:

```
g.fillRect(x-7,y-7,15,15);
```

If i'm correct this would make the head = new point(x,y) be in roughly in the center of the drawn rectangle. But I actually think that the code you have at this moment should be functioning correctly if you would hit the pixels perfectly.

If you need some more help, let me know, would be happy to help out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that there is a method called contains() in the Rectangle class. For the Point declaration,I declared it, but i just didnt add it in the code, just forgetten.Thank you again for your help and also a detailed explanation.

Comment: I will edit my post in order for you to see how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I don't see any setRemove() method in your food class and also that the render method can only my used in the paintComponent(Graphics g) method, not in the main() method . So couldn't the whole code of the main method( from your declaration of time variable) to the paintComponent() method???

Comment: I'll keep the answer here clean, I've edited it again so it only contains my initial statements. It would take us off topic too much to explain how I would do things. on youtube you can search for TheChernoProject, that's a guy who has some game programming tutorials. They are a little outdated since they're about 4 years old. But should still be fine to get you started on knowing some basics. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your snake would move if you press the arrow key and let go.  This cause the snake to "skip" over some distance. Thus causing your check to not match.

If you try the sample code I paste below,  "holding the arrow key to collide your snake with food" it will increase the score.
try this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game2 extends JComponent implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public int x = 350, y = 350;
    public static Game2 game;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;
    public int vx, vy, fx, fy, score;

    public Point head;
    public Random generator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = new Game2();
    }

    public Game2() {
        generator = new Random();
        fx = 7 + generator.nextInt(780);
        fy = 7 + generator.nextInt(780);
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setSize(700, 700);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Timer t = new Timer(10, this);

        window.add(this);

        window.addKeyListener(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
        head = new Point(x, y);

        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int speed = 1;
        if (up) {
            vy = -speed;
            y = y + vy;
        }
        if (down) {
            vy = speed;
            y = y + vy;
        }
        if (left) {
            vx = -speed;
            x = x + vx;
        }
        if (right) {
            vx = speed;
            x = x + vx;
        }
        if (x == 0 && vx == -speed) {
            x = 800;
            vy = 0;
        }
        if (x == 800 && vx == speed) {
            x = 0;
            vy = 0;
        }
        if (y == 0 && vy == -speed) {
            y = 800;
            vx = 0;
        }
        if (y == 800 && vy == speed) {
            y = 0;
            vx = 0;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up = true;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            up = false;
            down = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = true;
            right = false;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = true;
        }
        if (foodPhysics() == true) {
            score++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
        foodRender(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 25, 25));
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(score), 500, 500);
    }

    //improve this by limiting the fx, fy in bound
    public void foodRender(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(fx, fy, 15, 15);
    }

    public boolean foodPhysics() {

        return Math.abs(x-fx) < 30 && Math.abs(y-fy) < 30;
    }

}
```

One, I slowed down your snake so easier to test.
Two,  I changed your check collision method.

Comment: Increase your snake if you want,  I made it slow so it's easier to see the effect.  To increase your speed,  up count the int speed variable.